# Elegant way to serve static resources from memory in Spring / Servlet / Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, caching, servlets

Suppose I want to improve performance by loading whole contents of `.css`, `.js` and some other files (favicon, some images) directly from RAM memory without hitting disk.

I can just write servlet/controller which will load those files on context init or first request and cache in simple `String`, but **is there any standard already made solution to serve selected static resources from RAM in Spring, Servlets or Tomcat specification?**

It would be nice to support proper headers also (cache-control etc.).

Comment: Have you considered simply deploying a web cache like Squid or Nginx in front of your Tomcat instance?

Comment: @paulsm4 I think that word "simply" belongs more to simple servlet or controller than setting up and integrating second webserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat caches static files by default.

You can configure caching behaviour in context.xml. In particular (from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html):

*cacheMaxSize*
Maximum size of the static resource cache in kilobytes. If not specified, the default value is 10240 (10 megabytes).

*cacheObjectMaxSize*
Maximum size of the static resource that will be placed in the cache. If not specified, the default value is 512 (512 kilobytes). If this value is greater than cacheMaxSize/20 it will be reduced to cacheMaxSize/20.

*cacheTTL*
Amount of time in milliseconds between cache entries revalidation. If not specified, the default value is 5000 (5 seconds).

*cachingAllowed*
If the value of this flag is true, the cache for static resources will be used. If not specified, the default value of the flag is true.

Comment: does it apply when request goes through Spring servlet dispatcher and `<mvc:resource` ?

Comment: no, files defined by <mvc:resource/> are served by some internal spring servlet. Though the documentation says that at least Last-Modified HTTP header is checked for these files.