# <mvc:resources> - Does it cache to memory? Spring 4.0.5

Tags: java, spring

Let the following:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And say 2000 requests come to

```
/resources/script/app/myhax.js
```

If I don't config anything, is `myhax.js` cached somehow into RAM and the rest of the requests served from there, or are all 2000 requests served from the real path of the file (HDD, usually)? Can Spring be configured to keep this file in RAM after it has been requested for future service directly from memory?

Comment: Nothing is cached it is read from the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring caches no resources. But there is a possibility in order to allow resources to be cached.

You can specify [cache-period](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/MvcResources.html)(to send cache headers with a given max-age value) E.g.

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="3600"/>
```

OR

`mvc:resources` are backed by [ResourceHttpRequestHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html), so you can create your own subclass that extends `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` and implement caching logic by overriding appropriate methods e.g.`writeContent`(Note you can refer to documentation or source code to find out list of available methods) and use this new subclass in spring config.
E.g.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CacheResourceHandler extends ResourceHttpRequestHandler {

        private Map<URL, byte[]> cache = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        protected void writeContent(HttpServletResponse resp, Resource rsc) throws IOException {
            byte[] buff = cache.get(rsc.getURL());

            //if not in cache
            if (buff == null) {
                //add to cache
                buff = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(rsc.getInputStream());
                cache.put(rsc.getURL(), buff);
            }

            //return cache version
            StreamUtils.copy(buff, resp.getOutputStream());
        }

    }
```

Xml configuration

We need to comment out or delete previous resource mapping

```
 <!--<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />-->
```

Next we need to declare our cache handler bean

```
  <bean id="staticResources" class="CacheResourceHandler">
          <property name="locations" value="/resources/"/> 
    </bean>
```

Finally, we are going to use SimpleUrlHandlerMapping declared above that implements `HandlerMapping` interface in order to map from URLS to request handler beans. All we need is to pass our bean for mapping

```
   <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
          <property name="mappings">
                 <value>/resources/**=staticResources</value>
          </property>
   </bean>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow said that mvc:resources dodges tomcat caching, for me suggesting your 2nd solution doesn't work? (answer's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778293/elegant-way-to-serve-static-resources-from-memory-in-spring-servlet-tomcat)

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki You are right Thanks for the link. Answer updated

Comment: I'm trying to do your solution, but fail to find the way to swap out the ResourceHttpRequestHandler class from under <resources> :(

Comment: but, how does it change anything, if the two beans you defined are not injected anywhere? Are they some kind of "standard" named ones?

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki Added explanation

Comment: isn't cache-period for client side (browser) caching info?

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki Yes it is ,I mentioned it just for the sake of your knowledge

Comment: In case someone else doesn't know as me, apparently creating a bean with the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping class is automatically used, no need to inject it anywhere. That's what i didn't see. Otherwise i managed to do this solution, thanks!

Comment: Oh, there is a big problem with it however, the disk operation is not in getResource() but in writeContent() (the spring implementation of Resource fethes it's inputstream lazy style). If you could modify your sample, i would accept it as an answer.

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki Updated,  `writeContent` was the one which I mentioned in original post :) . I mentioned `getResource` so that you will have better understanding of what and how spring is doing. Hope it helps